# Reversing string using stack

Tags: c

I have a problem with reversing string using stack structure.

I made some code to reverse 'apple' to 'elppa' and seems like it worked well...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 5

typedef int element;

element stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];

int top = -1;

void initialize() {
    top = -1;
}

int isEmpty() {
    return (top == -1);
}

int isFull() {
    return (top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1));
}

void push(element item) {
    if (isFull()) {
        printf("stack is full, cannot add element.\n");
    }
    else{
        stack[++top] = item;
    }
}

element pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("stack is empty\n");
    }
    else {
        return stack[top--];
    }
}

char* reverse(char* s) {
    const int len = sizeof(s) + 1;
    char* rstring = new char[len];
    initialize();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        push(s[i]);
    }
    int tmp = 0;
    while(isEmpty()==false){
        rstring[tmp++]=pop();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", rstring[i]);
    }
    return rstring;
}

void main() {
    char* str1 = "apple";
    char* str2 = reverse(str1);

    printf("before : %s \n", str1);
    printf("after : %s \n", str2);
    getchar();
}
```

[the result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl0jk.jpg) I got the answer(elppa) but it also printed out some other characters what I wasn`t intended. Why I got this thing? It may something to do with memory array or something but do not know exactly what was happened memory. How to fix the problem?

Comment: You temporarily ignored the fact that C strings need a binary zero at the end, so that various pieces of stock code (`printf` in this case) know when to stop printing.

Comment: You can't get string length by `sizeof` ! this macro return length of `(char *)` that is 4 (or 8). use `strlen` function in your `reverse` function.

Comment: @HamidRezaMehrabian: well spotted! So the first 8 (I'm just guessing) characters come from `sizeof`, and the 9th from not terminating the string.

Comment: @RadLexus you are right sir but it doesn`t fix the problem

Comment: This code is not valid C nor is it valid C++. What kind of crappy compiler let this code through?

Comment: @Lundin You mean `void main`? Between that and the extra `getchar` at the end, this looks like a DOS program.

Comment: @Potatoswatter `char* rstring = new char[len];` is not valid C. The includes are not valid C++.

Comment: So for the record, if the compiler is Turbo C++ from 1990, go and introduce your teacher's face to a blunt object, then quit your harmful programming class, then download a modern compiler. Once that is sorted, you can start to worry about the errors in your code.

Comment: @Lundin That was the best advice ever I heard. Thank you.

Comment: @Lundin `new char[len]` allocates a character array on the heap. What's wrong with that? (You might be thinking of C99 VLAs on the stack, but compilers accept that as a special feature, not being "crappy.") As for the includes, they're old-fashioned and deprecated but they are specified by the C++ standard.

Comment: @Potatoswatter As I said, the `new` keyword is not valid C. There is nothing wrong with it in _C++_ but this question is supposedly not about C++.

Comment: @Lundin Wow, my brain is just inserting `++` everywhere :P

Comment: @timedeveloper I want you to download `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't taken into account the string termination character `'\0'`. You are printing the sting using %s with printf.

Once rstring has been calculated after unwinding the stack, you should append `'\0'` to rstring. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Oh I inserted push('\0'); before pushing other elements and I fixed my problem. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

By using `sizeof` you will get the data_type size (in this case, size of char*) in bytes. You should use `strlen` instead.

Comment: you are totally right sir but it does not fix the problem

Comment: Is it random "strange character" or just a same character?